# Spring webflux. Memory leak

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I found that spring webflux doesn't allow gc to collect a garbage.
I simplified my code. There is simple pipeline:

```
@Configuration
class RouterConfig(
    val operationRepository: OperationRepository // r2dbc repository fun findOperationsRangeForCarrier(ids: Collection<Long>,start: LocalDateTime,end: LocalDateTime): Flux<TPPOperation>
) {
    val csvMapper = CsvMapper().apply { findAndRegisterModules() }
    val writer = csvMapper.writer(csvMapper.schemaFor(TPPOperation::class.java).withoutHeader())

    val carrierIds = listOf<Long>(1)
    val start = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0)
    val end = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0)

    @Bean
    fun routing(): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> = router {
        accept(MediaType.ALL).nest {
            GET("/test") {
                operationRepository.findOperationsRangeForCarrier(carrierIds, start, end) // returns about 800_000 items
                    .map { writer.writeValueAsBytes(it) }
                    .reduce(ByteArrayOutputStream()) { output, el ->
                        output.write(el)
                        output
                    }
                    .map { output -> output.toByteArray() } // 229Mb
                    .flatMap {
                        ServerResponse.ok()
                            .headers { httpHeaders ->
                                httpHeaders.contentType = MediaType("application", "force-download")
                                httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=test.csv")
                            }
                            .bodyValue(ByteArrayResource(it))
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result file is downloaded succesfully and has a size about 229Mb.
After several sequential requests I found that the memory wasn't release and in result I had OOM.
Heap dump showed that the result byte arrays are live objects and gc can't collect them because they have gc root WindowsSelectorImpl.
What should I do to release the result bytearray which already can't be live object.
I created heap dump after minutes of request was finished: [image]

Show nearest gc roots:
[image]

Comment: I created an example project for reproducing this case https://github.com/typik89/webfluxMemoryRetroProject

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: it's rdbc issue. See https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql/issues/492